# My component don't re-render after a state change

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I'm new to react and Redux and I'm having problems with async state changes.
Im trying to re-render the child component after an api call. The api is called and returns a new state but the re-render  [never happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czhgq.png) 
I know it's probably a problem of basic usage but I've been stuck in this for hours and I can't get through it.

Thanks for your help

```js
//This is my parent component
@connect(state => ({example: state.example }))
class DetectorlistContainer extends Component {
  render() {
        const {example} = this.props;
    return (
      <DetectorlistComponent detectors={example.data}/>
    )

  }
}

//This is my child component
class DetectorlistComponent extends Component {
  render () {
      if (this.props.detectors.length == 0) {
          console.log('no data');
          return (<div className="DetectorListComponent">NNo detectors</div>);
      }
    return (
        <div className="DetectorListComponent">
            <Grid>
                <Row>
                    {console.log('there is data')}
                </Row>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

//this is my reducer

function exampleReducer(
    state = {
        isLoading: false,
        currentDetector: undefined,
        data: [],
        error: false
    },
    action = null) {
 switch(action.type) {
  case types.RECV_ERROR:
   return Object.assign({}, state, {isLoading: false, data: action.data, error: true});
  case types.RECV_DATA:
   return Object.assign({}, state, {isLoading: false, data: action.data, error: false });
  case types.REQ_DATA:
   return Object.assign({}, state, {isLoading: true, error: false });
  default:
   return state;
 }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
 example: exampleReducer
});

//this is my fetchData action

export function fetchData(url) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(requestData());
        return axios({
            url: url,
            timeout: 20000,
            method: 'get',
            responseType: 'json'
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log('fetch data correct')
                console.log(response.data);
                dispatch(receiveData(response.data));
            })
            .catch(function (response) {
                console.log('fetch data error')
                dispatch(receiveError(response.data));
                dispatch(pushState(null, '/error'));
            })
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you create your actions? What does `receiveData` do? http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html

Comment: Also, what is your `@connect` doing? How does it connect to `DetectorlistContainer`?